# Apache 2 cannot successfully load module?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, apache-modules, mod-auth-openidc

We have an older ubuntu 14 server that is currently working and has apache2 running on and I'm attempting to install an open idc module to get SSO working at our company.  I know...Ubuntu 14 is old, but that's a whole other can of worms...

When I run

```
apachectl -M
```

It successfully shows auth_openidc_module (shared)
I also verified that ‘auth_openidc.conf’ is in my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled directory

However when I add
in my apache2.conf :

```
 LoadModule auth_openidc_module module/mod_auth_openidc.so
    include mods-enabled/auth_openidc.conf
    <Location / >
           AuthType openid-connect
           Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

and perform a 'apachectl -M' command I get the following error.

'Syntax error on line 57 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load module/mod_auth_openidc.so into server: /etc/apache2/module/mod_auth_openidc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action '-M' failed.'

Another point of confusion, I don't see any directory named 'auth_openidc_module' or any .so file anywhere within Apache.  I have seen some posts that the .so files might be in '/usr/lib64/httpd/modules' but my lib64 directory is blank...

I'm a newbie to all of this...what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I don't have it working successfully yet, but I did get the error 'can't find' error fixed.  The directory for modules on our server was '/usr/lib/apache2/modules/'  NOT '/usr/lib64/httpd/modules'